# Google app script - make if condition with json data

Tags: google-apps-script

I cannot find match condition with google app script
here i have json data contain "externalIds" and contain "type=organization, value=TIS-00096028"
I would like to get "value=TIS-00096028" but some data has externalIds some are not.
so i dont know what condition can fix it(I have not find "externalIds.Isempty" function or "find(externalIds)" function )

Some part of code

```
for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){

          json = JSON.parse(users[i])
          Logger.log(i)
          Logger.log(json)
          Logger.log(typeof(json))
          Logger.log(JSON.stringify(users[i]))
          Logger.log(typeof(JSON.stringify(users[i])))
          Logger.log(json["externalIds"])
          //Logger.log(typeof(json["externalIds"]))

          //Logger.log(json["externalIds"][0]["value"])

          if(json["externalIds"].ContenService ="null"){
            empolyee_code=""
            Logger.log("No empolyee_code "+empolyee_code)
          }
          else{
            empolyee_code = json["externalIds"][0]["value"];
            Logger.log("empolyee_code "+empolyee_code)
          }
          rows.push([users[i].name.givenName, 
                     users[i].name.familyName, 
                     users[i].primaryEmail,
                     getUserOrg(users[i].primaryEmail, users[i].orgUnitPath),
                     getStatus(users[i].suspended),
                     users[i].lastLoginTime.slice(0,10),
                     empolyee_code,
                     
                    ]);        


      }
```

In red circle i try to write some condition but not work.
In Excution log is a one json data of data.
[image]
here some json data contain "externalIds" field

```
    {isDelegatedAdmin=false, addresses=[{formatted=DSM, type=work, primary=true}], isEnforcedIn2Sv=true, creationTime=2015-10-08T16:01:13.000Z, kind=admin#directory#user, lastLoginTime=2022-06-22T05:23:12.000Z, archived=false, suspended=false, languages=[{preference=preferred, languageCode=en}], nonEditableAliases=[a_achara@tripetch-isuzu.co.th.test-google-a.com, a_achara@g.tripetch-isuzu.co.th], isEnrolledIn2Sv=true, recoveryPhone=+66896847807, orgUnitPath=/Google/Tripetch (Google)/TIS, isAdmin=false, thumbnailPhotoEtag="Ap9BCC4uRt3h_SrDO0G_EX9zYVZwuEfjT_jX812ihkE/ZDtakkHxKrU_zGt1nyNxvPl7a88", agreedToTerms=true, customerId=C019gbqss, etag="Ap9BCC4uRt3h_SrDO0G_EX9zYVZwuEfjT_jX812ihkE/-E_Pbpdoymtn76EXDbsRNGh2ZWU", emails=[{address=a_achara@tripetch-isuzu.co.th, primary=true}, {address=a_achara@tripetch-isuzu.co.th.test-google-a.com}, {address=a_achara@g.tripetch-isuzu.co.th}], thumbnailPhotoUrl=https://www.google.com/s2/photos/private/AIbEiAIAAABECMrAkLP6qcXoxAEiC3ZjYXJkX3Bob3RvKig3ODk1NWNmN2ZjMDdiMmFiZmY4MmEwZjRkMTMwNTRjMmE0Y2U5YjgzMAG2IKR1qfqcYesdZgOUe5fVpfBDag, name={familyName=ANUMORN, givenName=ACHARA, fullName=ACHARA ANUMORN}, ipWhitelisted=false, externalIds=[{type=organization, value=TIS-00096028}], changePasswordAtNextLogin=false, phones=[{value=3261, type=work}], primaryEmail=a_achara@tripetch-isuzu.co.th, id=114182140133404581962, includeInGlobalAddressList=true, isMailboxSetup=true}
```

This is second data does not contain "externalIds":[{"value":"TIS-000xxxx","type":"organization"}]
[image]

Comment: Look into [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: Your screen shot code doesn't match your posted code.  It would seem `if(!json["externalIds"]){` should work since undefined is also falsy.